# Error appears only the first call, once the screen opens again, the error disappears,

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, getter

As per the screenshot once I open the screen it gives me the error "**The getter 'email' was called on null**." but if I just click back button, then open the screen again, it works well without any error,

the purpose of the screen is the account owner see the notes that was sent to him from the admin account

[This is the error appears only one time after opening the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTuFg.jpg)

[Here the same screen without any error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufF1G.jpg)

Here is the codes in dart where the tap to screen exists

```js
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart' show CupertinoIcons;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notification_permissions/notification_permissions.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rate_my_app/rate_my_app.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import '../../app.dart';
import '../../common/config.dart';
import '../../common/constants.dart';
import '../../common/tools.dart';
import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../../models/index.dart' show AppModel, User, UserModel, WishListModel;
import '../../routes/flux_navigate.dart';
import '../../screens/blogs/post_screen.dart';
import '../../services/index.dart';
import '../../widgets/common/webview.dart';
import '../custom/smartchat.dart';
import '../index.dart';
import '../users/user_point.dart';
import 'currencies.dart';
import 'language.dart';
import 'notification.dart';
import '../../common/config.dart' as config;
import 'package:cespohm/screens/bywaleed/booking_admin_screen.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/screens/bywaleed/docor_note_tap.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/screens/bywaleed/user_search_new_screen.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/screens/bywaleed/doctor_notes_user_screen.dart';

class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic> settings;
  final String background;
  final User user;
  final VoidCallback onLogout;
  final bool showChat;

  SettingScreen({
    this.user,
    this.onLogout,
    this.settings,
    this.background,
    this.showChat,
  });

  @override
  _SettingScreenState createState() {
    return _SettingScreenState();
  }
}

class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen>
    with
        TickerProviderStateMixin,
        WidgetsBindingObserver,
        AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SettingScreen> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  final bannerHigh = 150.0;
  bool enabledNotification = true;
  final RateMyApp _rateMyApp = RateMyApp(
      // rate app on store
      minDays: 7,
      minLaunches: 10,
      remindDays: 7,
      remindLaunches: 10,
      googlePlayIdentifier: kStoreIdentifier['android'],
      appStoreIdentifier: kStoreIdentifier['ios']);

  void showRateMyApp() {
    _rateMyApp.showRateDialog(
      context,
      title: S.of(context).rateTheApp,
      // The dialog title.
      message: S.of(context).rateThisAppDescription,
      // The dialog message.
      rateButton: S.of(context).rate.toUpperCase(),
      // The dialog "rate" button text.
      noButton: S.of(context).noThanks.toUpperCase(),
      // The dialog "no" button text.
      laterButton: S.of(context).maybeLater.toUpperCase(),
      // The dialog "later" button text.
      listener: (button) {
        // The button click listener (useful if you want to cancel the click event).
        switch (button) {
          case RateMyAppDialogButton.rate:
            break;
          case RateMyAppDialogButton.later:
            break;
          case RateMyAppDialogButton.no:
            break;
        }

        return true; // Return false if you want to cancel the click event.
      },
      // Set to false if you want to show the native Apple app rating dialog on iOS.
      dialogStyle: const DialogStyle(),
      // Custom dialog styles.
      // Called when the user dismissed the dialog (either by taping outside or by pressing the "back" button).
      // actionsBuilder: (_) => [], // This one allows you to use your own buttons.
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      await checkNotificationPermission();
    });
    _rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
      // state of rating the app
      if (_rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) {
        showRateMyApp();
      }
    });
  }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   Utils.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(false);
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  Future<void> checkNotificationPermission() async {
    if (!isAndroid || isIos) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await NotificationPermissions.getNotificationPermissionStatus()
          .then((status) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            enabledNotification = status == PermissionStatus.granted;
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      printLog('[Settings Screen] : ${err.toString()}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      checkNotificationPermission();
    }
  }

  /// Render the Admin Vendor Menu
  Widget renderVendorAdmin() {
    if (!(widget.user != null ? widget.user.isVendor ?? false : false)) {
      return Container();
    }

    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
      elevation: 0,
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          final String langCode =
              Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false).langCode;

          if (unsupportedLanguages.contains(langCode)) {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                  S.of(context).thisFeatureDoesNotSupportTheCurrentLanguage),
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            );
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            return;
          }
          FluxNavigate.push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  Services().widget.getAdminVendorScreen(context, widget.user),
            ),
            forceRootNavigator: true,
          );
        },
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.dashboard,
          size: 24,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
        title: Text(
          S.of(context).vendorAdmin,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          size: 18,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Render the custom profile link via Webview
  /// Example show some special profile on the woocommerce site: wallet, wishlist...
  Widget renderWebViewProfile() {
    if (widget.user == null) {
      return Container();
    }

    var base64Str = Utils.encodeCookie(widget.user.cookie);
    var profileURL = '${serverConfig["url"]}/my-account?cookie=$base64Str';

    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
      elevation: 0,
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WebView(
                  url: profileURL, title: S.of(context).updateUserInfor),
            ),
          );
        },
        leading: Icon(
          CupertinoIcons.profile_circled,
          size: 24,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
        title: Text(
          S.of(context).updateUserInfor,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          size: 18,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget renderItem(value) {
    IconData icon;
    String title;
    Widget trailing;
    Function() onTap;
    bool isMultiVendor = kFluxStoreMV.contains(serverConfig['type']);
    switch (value) {
      case 'bookingAdmin':
        if (widget.user == null ) {
          return Container();
        }
        else if(widget.user.email == config.adminEmail || widget.user.email == config.adminEmailTwo && widget.user != null )
        {
          icon = FontAwesomeIcons.keyboard;
          title = S.of(context).checkout;
          trailing =
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 18, color: kGrey600);
          onTap = () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const BookingAdminScreen()),
          );

        }
        else {
          return Container();
        }
        break;

      case 'addDoctorNote':
        if (widget.user == null ) {
          return Container();
        }
        else if(widget.user.isVendor && widget.user != null )
        {
          icon = FontAwesomeIcons.edit;
          title = S.of(context).continueToShipping;
          trailing =
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 18, color: kGrey600);
          onTap = () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const UserSearchNewScreen()),
          );

        }
        else {
          return Container();
        }
        break;
/// here is the tap to the screen where there is the error
      case 'yourDoctorNotes':
        if (widget.user == null || widget.user.email == config.adminEmail || widget.user.email == config.adminEmailTwo ) {
          return Container();
        }
        else if(!widget.user.isVendor)
        {

          icon = FontAwesomeIcons.notesMedical;
          title = S.of(context).french;
          trailing =
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 18, color: kGrey600);
          onTap = () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>   DoctorNoteUserScreen(senderUser: widget.user,)),
          );

        }
        else {
          return Container();
        }
        break;


      case 'chat':
```

here is the dart code of the screen where is the error

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/bywaleed_model/user_search_new_model.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/bywaleed_model/user_search_new_provider.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase_auth;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../generated/l10n.dart' as word;
import '../../models/index.dart' show AppModel, Store, User, UserModel ;

final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firebase_auth.User loggedInUser;
class DoctorNoteUserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final User senderUser;
   DoctorNoteUserScreen({
    Key key,
    this.senderUser,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userSearchProvider = Provider.of<UserSearchProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          word.S.of(context).french,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
        leading: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List<UserSearchModel>>(
          stream: userSearchProvider.userstwo,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData  ) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
              );
            }   else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 40.0,
                                ),
                                Text(word.S.of(context).french,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Divider(
                                  thickness: 1.0,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index].doctorNote!=null?snapshot.data[index].doctorNote: 'No Notes Yet',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
          }),
    
    );
  }
}
```

here is the dart code of the service

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/bywaleed_model/user_search_new_model.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/bywaleed_model/user_search_new_provider.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/user_model.dart';

class UserSearchService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final userModel = UserModel();

  //Get Entries
  Stream<List<UserSearchModel>> getEntries(){
    return _db
        .collection('users')
        .orderBy('firstName', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => UserSearchModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }

/// here is the firebase collection where the error exists 
  Stream<List<UserSearchModel>> getEntriesTwo(){
    return _db
        .collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: userModel.user.email)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => UserSearchModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }

}
```

here is the model

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserSearchModel {
  final String date;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String phone;
  final String email;
  final String searchKey;
  final String doctorNote;
  final String bYDoctor;
  final String uID;




  UserSearchModel(
      {this.date,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.phone,
      this.email,
      this.searchKey,
      this.doctorNote,
      this.bYDoctor,



      this.uID});

  // creating a Trip object from a firebase snapshot
  UserSearchModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) :
        date = snapshot['date'],
        firstName = snapshot['firstName'].toDate(),
        lastName = snapshot['lastName'].toDate(),
        phone = snapshot['phone'],
        email = snapshot['email'],
        searchKey = snapshot['searchKey'],
        doctorNote = snapshot['doctorNote'],
        bYDoctor = snapshot['bYDoctor'],
        uID = snapshot.id;

  factory UserSearchModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserSearchModel(
        date: json['createdAt'],
        firstName: json['firstName'],
        lastName: json['lastName'],
        phone: json['phone'],
        email: json['email'],
        searchKey: json['searchKey'],
        doctorNote: json['doctorNote'],
        bYDoctor: json['bYDoctor'],
        uID: json['uID']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'createdAt': date,
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'phone': phone,
      'email': email,
      'searchKey': searchKey,
      'doctorNote': doctorNote,
      'bYDoctor': bYDoctor,
      'uID': uID,

    };
  }
}
```

Here is the provider

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/bywaleed_model/user_search_new_model.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:cespohm/services/bywaleed/user_search_new_service.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class UserSearchProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final userSearchService = UserSearchService();
  final userModel = UserModel();
  DateTime _date;
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  String _phone;
  String _email;
  String _searchKey;
  String _doctorNote;
  String _bYDoctor;
  String _uID;



  var uuid = Uuid();

//Getters
  DateTime get date => _date;
  String get firstName => _firstName;
  String get lastName => _lastName;
  String get phone => _phone;
  String get email => _email;
  String get searchKey => _searchKey;
  String get doctorNote => _doctorNote;
  String get byDoctor => _bYDoctor;
  String get uID => _uID;


  Stream<List<UserSearchModel>> get users => userSearchService.getEntries();
  Stream<List<UserSearchModel>> get userstwo => userSearchService.getEntriesTwo();

  //Setters
  set changeDate(DateTime date) {
    _date = date;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeFirstName(String firstName) {
    _firstName = firstName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeLastName(String lastName) {
    _lastName = lastName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changePhone(String phone) {
    _phone = phone;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeEmail(String email) {
    _email = email;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeSearchKey(String searchKey) {
    _searchKey = searchKey;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeDoctorNote(String doctorNote) {
    _doctorNote = doctorNote;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeBYDoctor(String bYDoctor) {
    _bYDoctor = bYDoctor;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeuID(String uID) {
    _uID = uID;
    notifyListeners();
  }


  //Functions
  loadAll(UserSearchModel userSearchModel) {
    if (userSearchModel != null) {
      _date = DateTime.parse(userSearchModel.date);
      _firstName = userSearchModel.firstName;
      _lastName = userSearchModel.lastName;
      _phone = userSearchModel.phone;
      _email = userSearchModel.email;
      _searchKey = userSearchModel.searchKey;
      _doctorNote = userSearchModel.doctorNote;
      _bYDoctor = userModel.user.email;
      _uID = userSearchModel.uID;


    } else {
      _date = DateTime.now();
      _firstName = null;
      _lastName = null;
      _phone = null;
      _email = null;
      _searchKey = null;
      _doctorNote = null;
      _bYDoctor = null;
      _uID = null;



    }
  }

  saveEntry() {
    if (_email == null) {
      //Add
      var newUserModel = UserSearchModel(
          date: _date.toIso8601String(),
          firstName: _firstName,
          lastName: _lastName,
          phone: _phone,
          email: _email,
          searchKey: _searchKey,
          doctorNote: _doctorNote,
          bYDoctor: _bYDoctor,

          uID: _uID);


      print(newUserModel.email);
      userSearchService.setEntry(newUserModel);
    } else {
      //Edit
      var updatedEntry = UserSearchModel(
          date: _date.toIso8601String(),
          firstName: _firstName,
          lastName: _lastName,
          phone: _phone,
          email: _email,
          searchKey: _searchKey,
          doctorNote: _doctorNote,
          bYDoctor: _bYDoctor,

          uID: _uID);
      userSearchService.setEntry(updatedEntry);
    }
  }

  removeEntry(String entryId) {
    userSearchService.removeEntry(entryId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your `User` object is initialised. This error appears because `user.email` is accessed, but your `User` object is `null`. Make sure your code considers loading time for the user object if it comes from the API, and has appropriate checks for the case when `user == null`.